# Use bootstrap modal with href tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that looks like this

```
Name  Occupation  Detail
abc   student     details
```

i want to set a bootstrap modal link on details column, which not only works as a model but also picks the id of that specific row.

At present i am working with this code

```
echo "<td><a href='#myModal'?id=".$row['id']."\" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal '>Details</a></td>";
```

Modal is working properly but i am not able to use id of the row properly with the modal
Would appreciate if someone could help me

Comment: is that an extra double quote at the end of:  $row['id']."\"  maybe try taking out the  \"  and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/0u19axax/1/

You can use `show.bs.modal` event to extract data from your `a`.

```
 $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e){
     console.log($(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id'))
 })
```

I moved the id to `data-id` because it did not work with the id in `href`

```
<a href='#myModal' data-id='.$row['id'].' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal '>Details</a>
```

Sorry, I don't know PHP so I'm not sure it'll work PHP wise.